# SUMIF in Google Sheets for a month and if a column contains text

Tags: google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, sumifs

I have some simple data in the following format:

[image]

I need to make a sum of the last column, but based on the text in Domain column. The resulting table should be like this...given the text filtering needed, I'm not using pivot tables.

[image]

To do this, for July Domain 1 for example, I have a formula like this:

```
=SUMIFS(C:C, MONTH(A:A), 7, B:B, "domain1.")
```

And for the rest of the domains:

```
=SUMIFS(C:C, MONTH(A:A), 7, B:B, "<>domain1.")
```

I am using `SUMIFS` because I need the multiple conditionals. But this formula above gives an error:

> ***Error**: Array arguments to SUMIFS are of different size.*

The columns are all structured as A:A, B:B, etc. What is going wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
MONTH(A:A)
```

will output only one cell unless you wrap your formula into `INDEX` or `ARRAYFORMULA`:

```
=INDEX(SUMIFS(C:C, MONTH(A:A), 7, B:B, "<>domain1.*"))
```

[image]

---

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({TEXT(A2:A, "mmmm"), B2:C}, 
 "select Col1,sum(Col3) 
  where not Col2 contains 'domain1.' 
    and Col3 is not null 
  group by Col1 
  label sum(Col3)''"))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thank you. The `ARRAYFORMULA` works! However, the text matching doesn't. Is that why you recommended the SQL query based approach? I'm also thinking I'll need to include the year in the conditions somehow.

Comment: for including year you can use proposed query formula and replace `mmmm` with `mmmm yyyy`

Comment: Oh, perfect. Yes the asterisk worked! Yay, thank you thank you!

Comment: Just for my knowledge, if I did want to create the kind of query format you suggested, how could I include the domain1 and the non-domain1 column using the same query?

Comment: not rly sure how to interpret your question... can you explain in more detail what are you after?

Comment: I figured it out. The asterisk is needed on both sides of a text to match, like SQL.